# Click Tabs and Background changes (not BG of tab)

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, tabs

What I'm trying to accomplish:

When a tab is clicked background of parent div changes to a specific color.

My thinking for the jQuery code was to removeclass() (current class) and then add new class. But it seems I need to add a dynamic class because once li is clicked it'll change class, which is why I added an array of classes.

I think what would work best is targeting active class and then adding new class to div when "li" is "active".

But this is what I have right now:

jQuery Code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var $tab1 = jQuery('#fusion-tab-design');
        var $tab2 = jQuery('#fusion-tab-seocontentcreation');
        var $tab3 = jQuery('#tab-f8bdac86ea321cb8b58');
        var $tab4 = jQuery('#tab-e7e9c83e3a31ecbd7c2');
        var $element_id = ["class1","class2","class3","class4"];

        var $bgCont = jQuery('#bgcoverchangey');
        var $currClass = $bgCont.attr('fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box fusion-blend-mode changeme hundred-percent-fullwidth');

        // $bgCont.addClass('class1'); //starts with bg 1


            $tab1.click(function(){
                if($currClass != 'fusion fullwidth fullwidth box fusion blend mode changeme hundred percent fullwidth class1'){
                     $bgCont.removeAttr('fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box fusion-blend-mode changeme hundred-percent-fullwidth' + $element_id);
                $bgCont.addClass(' class1');
                } else {
                    return false;
                };
            });

         $tab2.click(function(){
                if($currClass != 'fusion fullwidth fullwidth box fusion blend mode changeme hundred percent fullwidth class2'){
                     $bgCont.removeAttr('fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box fusion-blend-mode changeme hundred-percent-fullwidth'+ $element_id);
                $bgCont.addClass(' class2');
                } else {
                    return false;
                };
            });

          $tab3.click(function(){
                if($currClass != 'fusion fullwidth fullwidth box fusion blend mode changeme hundred percent fullwidth class3'){
                     $bgCont.removeAttr('fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box fusion-blend-mode changeme hundred-percent-fullwidth' + $element_id);
                $bgCont.addClass(' class3');
                } else {
                    return false;
                };
            });

          $tab4.click(function(){
                if($currClass != 'fusion fullwidth fullwidth box fusion blend mode changeme hundred percent fullwidth class4'){
                     $bgCont.removeAttr('fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box fusion-blend-mode changeme hundred-percent-fullwidth' + $element_id);
                $bgCont.addClass(' class4');
                } else {
                    return false;
                };
            });

   });
```

CSS:

```
.class1:{
background-color:red;
}
.class2:{
background-color:yellow;
}
.class3{
background-color:green;
}
.class4{
background-color:orange;
}
```

The code I'm using seems an exaggeration to something that may take less code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working properly because you're not updating the value of `currClass` this is only being set when the document loads, you either need to update it when the tab is clicked (recommended) or update it alongside the class (not really recommended).

There are also a few other issues, such as you're using `attr` functions when I believe you want to be using `addClass`, `removeClass`, and `hasClass`. These functions don't require you to pass in full class lists either, just the ones you want to add or remove.

An example addressing the issues listed above:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".colorChange").click(function(evt){
    var bgElement = $("#changeMe");
    bgElement.removeClass("pink green blue");
    bgElement.addClass($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```css
#changeMe{
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
 }

#changeMe.blue{
  background: lightblue;
 }
#changeMe.pink{
  background: pink;
 }
#changeMe.green{
  background: lightgreen;
 }
#changeMe.blue{
  background: lightblue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="changeMe"> My background will change</div>

<button type="button" class="colorChange" id="pink">Make pink!</button>
<button type="button" class="colorChange" id="green">Make green!</button>
<button type="button" class="colorChange" id="blue">Make blue!</button>
```

So in this code, any time a button with the class `colorChange` is clicked, I fetch the element I'm changing the background of. After that I attempt to remove all the potential background color classes it could have (this part could be done more cleanly but I wanted to keep it simple). After that I add on the button which was clicked's id as a class to the background change element. Leave a comment if you want me to clarify anything else in my example.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution you try to remove some attributes which I guess is not exactly what you want. What you do want is to reset the classes of your background element.

I'm not sure how your tabs are made, but here is a solution that involves a translate table, which resolves the clicked id to a predefined class. I guess this is a bit easier when working with a fixed system like wordpress - but I might be wrong here.

```js
jQuery( function( $ ) {
  // Define some basics
  const $background = $( '#bgcoverchangey' );
  // Just in case, if there are any other classes defined when loading the page - we will keep them in tact
  const defaultBackgroundClass = $background.attr( 'class' ) || '';
  
  // Define translate table, which id leads to what class
  const translateTable = {
    'tab-1': 'class1',
    'tab-2': 'class2',
    'tab-3': 'class3',
  }
  
  // One selector to catch them all
  $( '.tabs button' ).click( function() {
    // Check if id is in the translateTable
    const id = $( this ).attr( 'id' );
    const className = translateTable[ id ];
    if ( !className ) {
      return;
    }

    // Reset and append new class
    $background.attr( 'class', `${ defaultBackgroundClass } ${ className }` );
  } );
} );
```

```css
#bgcoverchangey {
  /* default background class */
  background: silver;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.class1 {
  background: pink !important;
}

.class2 {
  background: skyblue !important;
}

.class3 {
  background: lightgreen !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
  <button id="tab-1">Tab 1</button>
  <button id="tab-2">Tab 2</button>
  <button id="tab-3">Tab 3</button>
</div>
<div id="bgcoverchangey"></div>
```